# magento website color changed to original theme color after applying Content delivery network

Tags: cdn

we bought a new magento theme and we customized as per our needs.

we changed color of lot of menus, texts...etc.

we want to speed up the site.

so we did CDN[content delivery network] for our site.

after we did CDN, color of our site changed to original theme color.

what is the problem.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to disable the CDN? Is the color then back to normal?

Comment: yes, if we disabled coor, color will back to normal.....

Comment: hi @AnnaVölkl  again we are changing the colors, but it's taking one day to display in frontend after we did CDN.....

Comment: I think you need to explain your CDN setup a bit more in detail in your question. That helps people here to understand or reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Base Skin URL is setup correctly. It could be your custom theme is pushing for gzip or it contains custom built portions preventing Magento's native url rewrite from applying CDN urls to your skin files.

I suggest getting in touch with your CDN support, they have the best quess with pinpointing the exact problem in your setup.